# How to consist the containers in Docker?

Tags: linux, docker, server

Now I am developing the new content so building the server.

On my server, the base system is the Cent OS(7), I installed the Docker, pulled the cent os, and establish the "WEB SERVER container" Django with uwsgi and nginx.

However I want to up the service, (Database with postgres), what is the best way to do it?

1. Install postgres on my existing container (with web server)
2. Build up the new container only for database.

and I want to know each advantage and weak point of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the data in the database after a restart, the database shouldn't be in a container but on the host. I will assume you want the db in a container as well.

Setting up a second container is a lot more work. You should find a way that the containers know about each other's address. The address changes each time you start the container, so you need to make some scripts on the host. The host must find out the ip-adresses and inform the containers.

The containers might want to update the /etc/hosts file with the address of the other container. When you want to emulate different servers and perform resilience tests this is a nice solution. You will need quite some bash knowledge before you get this running well.

In about all other situations choose for one container. Installing everything in one container is easier for setting up and for developing afterwards. Setting up Docker is just the environment where you want to do your real work. Tooling should help you with your real work, not take all your time and effort.

Comment: Then, what is the weak point of the "installing everything in one container"? the stability problem?

Comment: No, it is at least as stable as two containers. Running in one container is rather difficult to test how the webserver will react when the database server crashes. Of course you can kill the  database listener process for about the same result.

Comment: OKAY!! Thank you so much. But just one more thing, how about the build up it on the host? Do you recommend it?

Comment: When you do not want to start with a clean database everytime you start your container,  it is easier and quicker to set it up on the host (when you are root there).  Just write some reset.sql statements when you want to run some standard regression tests.

Comment: I don't get this answer - the addresses aren't a problem if you use links.

Comment: When you have 2 containers, 192.168.3.12 and 192.168.3.55, and no DNS-server, how can the webserver container resolve postgress.mouat.com ? Each time you start a container, Docker randomly gives another ip-address. So you should make the link after starting the container, cf by editing the /etc/hosts file.

Comment: @WalterA I don't understand. If you start the webserver and use --link to link to the database, /etc/hosts will be automatically populated with the name and IP of the database.

Comment: @Adrian I did not know docker had an option --link. This is indeed a lot easier than scripting it from the host!

Answer (score 1):

It's idiomatic to use two separate containers. Also, this is simpler - if you have two or more processes in a container, you need a parent process to monitor them (typically people use a process manager such as supervisord). With only one process, you won't need to do this.

By monitoring, I mainly mean that you need to make sure that all processes are correctly shutdown if the container receives a SIGSTOP signal. If you don't do this properly, you will end up with zombie processes. You won't need to worry about this if you only have a signal process or use a process manager.

Further, as Greg points out, having separate containers allows you to orchestrate and schedule the containers separately, so you can do update/change/scale/restart each container without affecting the other one.

Comment: Okay. I got it. but i wonder what is the technical problem? so.. It means just a monitoring issue?

Comment: it is just cleaner to use separate containers for separate processes in your application.  docker responds to the process exiting. if postgres is in one container, and your app is in another, postgres will know when either 'stops'.  you can then put your restart logic for either/both in a higher level (fleet,kubernetes,mesos) *instead* of inside your container. upgrades are easier if they are split (you could conceivably get a newer postgres image without changing your app image and vise-versa). It's simpler (what if there were 3, or 10 processes, would you  still 'merge' them?).